# jQuery dialog - how to get .ui-widget-shadow as a parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-dialog

When you style your own jQuery theme here: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ you can see that the modal dialog box in the section "Overlay and Shadow Classes" has a shadow around it. In the source code it shows that the dialog is actually wrapped with another div that has the class `ui-widget-shadow`.

For me this shadow is never visible because the dialog is not wrapped with this div when it is being created. Does anybody know how to get jQuery dialog wrap the dialog in this element so the shadow is visible?

Answer (score 0):

On the declaration of the dialog you just need to specify that class.

```
$(function () {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    ...
    dialogClass: 'ui-widget-shadow'
  });
});
```

Comment: no, unfortunately not... because it needs to get wrapped inside of it. if you specify that class then the class will be applied to the dialog itself, which results in something completely different...

Comment: you are right, I think it's probably better to have a separate class with `.dialogWithDropShadow{
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
} ` and then adding the class as I mentioned in the answer. Here's the [full code](http://jsbin.com/afupov/1/) and here another [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448813/jqueryui-how-to-make-a-shadow-around-a-dialog-box)